# How do I get the URL for an image stored in a subdirectory of a google-cloud-storage bucket

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have images storied in directories within a bucket in google-cloud-storage.
The images are not publicly viewable.
It's my understanding that I can 'sign' the image and the resulting URL will be publicly viewable for a specified time.
Nothing I've tried so far, however, seems to work.
Attempts to access the URL result in a `NoSuchKey` error.

Here's an example of the code I've tried.  Exactly what should the second parameter be that I pass to `BlobInfo.newBuilder`?  The documentation says it should be the `object name`.  Is that just the name of the file, i.e. `myimage.jpg`?

```java
URL getSignedImageUrl(String uri) {
  // ImageUploadDetails contains metadata about the image
  ImageUploadDetails imageUploadDetails = ImageUploadDetails.findByUri(uri)
  if (imageUploadDetails) {
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucket, imageUploadDetails.thumbnailPath)).build()
    URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES, Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature())
    return url // this URL, when converted to a String, doesn't work
} else {
  throw new ImageNotFoundException("Cannot open file: ${imageUploadDetails.thumbnailPath}")}
}
```

I expect the signed URL to be available to public users for the specified amount of time.  I would like to use it as the `src` value within an `image` tag.

Instead, what I'm getting is:

```xml
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
  <Details>
  obfuscated to protect the innocent
  </Details>
</Error>
```

Comment: Could you share the full code needed to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'd also suggest testing with a hard-coded bucket and blob name as demonstrated here ... https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.html#signUrl-com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.SignUrlOption...-

Answer (score 2):

By default, the url of an object would be `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`

For example:

```
- bucket1
  - folder1
    - image1.jpg  https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket1/folder1/image1.jpg
    - image2.jpg  https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket1/folder1/image2.jpg
- bucket2
  - image3.jpg    https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket2/image3.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you!  That resolves the issue.  I was not properly referencing the blob name